# Bash: Counting files and respective mime-types mismatch

Tags: bash, mime-types

I want to build a histogram of all the mine-types in a directory and its subdirectories. I have two commands

```
find dir/ -type f | xargs file --mime-type | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l
// returns 22690

find dir/ -type f | wc -l
// return 12097
```

So where does this mismatch come from and how can I work around this?\

Also, when creating the histogram with

```
find dir/ -type f | xargs file --mime-type | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

I get this big bucket `cannot` mime-type, with around 15000 hits and some `inode/directory` hits which should not occure since I run file with the type option. I am a bit confused where this all comes from.

Comment: "So where does this mismatch come from?" "I am a bit confused where this all comes from." If you have put in a tiny amount of effort by inspecting what's piped into `awk`, you'll know. One work around is to use the `-0` option of `file`, then filter out the filenames by removing up to null on every line (using `cut`, for instance). Of course this still doesn't capture the edge case of newlines in filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does some file have spaces in the name ? If so you have to use the `-print0` action instead of the implicit `print` (and the `--null` corresponding option for `xarg`) :

> -print0
>                 True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character (instead of the newline character that
>   -print uses).  This allows file names that contain  newlines
>                 or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output.  This option
>   corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.

So, in your case (edit: simplified thanks to flowit's comment):

```
find dir/ -type f -print0 | xargs --null file --mime-type -b | wc -l
```

Comment: I'd like to add a small change I added: I used the -b option for `file` so `awk` is not necessary at all.